Sum of cosines in generalized functions
I've came across such a task: prove that this equality holds (in generalized functions)
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{cos(nx)} = -\frac{1}{2} + \pi\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}{\delta_{2\pi k}}$$
I was able to find out that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{cos(nx)} = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{cos(x)}{1 - cos(x)}$
So now we need to show that $\frac{cos(x)}{1 - cos(x)} = \pi\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}{\delta_{2\pi k}}$ and I'm stuck here. Any help would be appreciated.

Notice that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos(nx)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{inx}$. Now take a look here.

@Gonçalo, yep, I've seen it. Actually I had never seen it before till the first time so I could not come up how to use it here., there is too much information for unexperienced user = )
Could you please clarify your hint?

All you need is in the short section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb#Fourier_series.
